# External url not working in inappbrowser

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, cordova

I am new to xcode,
if I implement an external url in phonegap using inappbrowser method is `window.open()`
the url is not loading, I get a white screen and at bottom a message is shown as load error and also load stop message not get.
I included `<plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />`
in config.xml and I used cordova2.3.0

```
function loadURL(url){
    var ref = window.open('url', '_blank','location=yes');
    ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) { 
        alert('start: ' + event.url);
        window.locaion.href='url';
    });
    ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) { 
        alert("open web site"+event.type); 
    });
    ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) { 
        alert(event.type); 
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you try   var ref=window.open('www.google.com', '_blank'); 
without last option 'location=yes'

Comment: now working cuccessfully, i changed my code as                                     var ref=window.open(encodeURI(url), '_blank','location=yes');

Answer (score 0):

Modify the access origin value as below in res/xml/config.xml.

`<access origin="*" subdomains="true" />`

Domain whitelisting in Apache Cordova is a security model that controls access to outside domains, such as http://google.com. The default security policy is to block all network access. This is the reason external url are not loading in InAppBrowser.

Refer to the following link for more information.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide